# Same printer connected via USB or WiFi recognized as two different printers

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, usb, printer, multi-function-printer

I connect my Canon Pixma TS5050 multi-functional printer to my Windows 10 laptop, sometimes by USB cable and sometimes by WiFi. Windows recognizes these two instances of the same printer as two different printers, which it has labeled `Canon TS5000 Series` (when connected via USB) and `Canon TS5000 Series (Copy 1)` (when connected via WiFi).

When I want to print, I have to select the "correct" printer in the printing dialog, which is a minor annoyance. However, Canon's own scanning program "IJ Scan Utility" seems to be permanently linked to the USB version of the printer, with no option to switch between the two.

Is there a way to make Windows 10 understand that the printer is the same device, whether connected via USB or WiFi?

*(Or alternatively, does anyone know how to switch scanners in the IJ Scan Utility?)*

Comment: In a similar situation, I renamed the latter connection "Wifi" so that humans knew which way.  Another option is to start clean and never use the USB connection.

Comment: You can simply remove the usb one and use only wifi. or remove the wifi one and use only usb. AFAIK there is no way to make windows realize these are the same printer as the way most printers identify themselves to windows is vastly different via usb and wifi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying problem is that Windows considers the port and the driver (the printer) as two separate entities.

That means that you can have multiple printers attached to the same port. This is used if you want the same printer with 2 different settings, e.g. one colour, the other black/white. Just install the printer twice, using the same port, and change default settings as needed.

Unfortunately, *every instance of a printer can only be connected to a single port*. Hence, using 2 ports means you will have 2 different printers.

As has been suggested in comments, the simplest solution is to use only one port to connect to the printer. If WiFi is reliable for you, then use that all the time - and enjoy the benefits of WiFi. If you have connection issues, then stick to USB only.

Comment: Exactly. If the USB port is redundant, delete it!

Comment: So there's no way to get around this feature?

Comment: I'm afraid not. You can rename the printers to something like "Canon_USB" and "Canon_WiFi". If using USB for scanning only, then rename the USB printer "Canon_Scan_only"